# Give UISlider progress bar rounded corners [Swift]

Tags: swift, uikit, uislider

I am wondering if anyone knows how to customize a UISlider to give the progress bar rounded corners (without Thumb Image) as shown in the following image:

**What I want:**
[image: UISlider progress bar with rounded corners]

**What I have now:**

[image: UISlider progress bar without rounded corners]
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That isn't how a UISlider works, so can't customize in that way. Instead, you would have to build your own custom view from scratch in order to get that display. The drawing part is trivially easy; getting your view to *act* like a slider (that is, if you want it to respond to touches and dragging) is pretty easy too.

Comment: With all due respect, why can't a UISlider work this way?

Comment: That's just not how it draws the track images. What a UIProgressView does is closer, obviously. But as I say, if you want the images drawn like that, you can just draw them yourself.

Comment: @aritroper this like asking why you can't turn on the fog lights on the car that doesn't have it. If you don't accept the answer 'manufacturer didn't assume such use case' I am not sure how can someone prove that something doesn't exist aside that it doesn't exist it is yours to examine if you don't believe. As matt said, you can always build your own car if you don't like what is provided.